# How to make a page redirect as instructed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am very new to web development and I'm struggling to understand why my redirect code isn't actually redirecting to the specified page. The code is definitely executing the redirect line as I can see it step through the line when I run on localhost.

Because I am very new to web development, I may not have approached this in the most optimal way, but I created a class to get the country from the IP address via an api call to ipstack.com. This takes the IP address as an input and I get that via ipify.org.

As I said, this possibly isn't the most optimal way of doing it, but it does work. I'm able to print the IP and Country out to the page happily.

The final bit, redirecting based on the country, is stumping me.
This is the code that I have in index.cshtml.cs

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
  public void OnGet()
  {
    string UserCountry = null; Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult x;

    //This is my class that gets the country from the IP
    UserCountry = redirect.getCountry(); 
    if (UserCountry == "MX"
    {  x = Redirect("http://www.example.com/mx"); }
    else
    {  x = Redirect("http://www.example.com/us"); }
  }
}
```

The code seems to compile happily and if I put a break on the line:
if (UserCountry... 
I can see that UserCountry is definitely being set to the right country (I've tested with an MX and a US IP address) and both code paths execute but the redirect never happens.

If I inspect x I can see the correct url in the url property of x but I assume this is from the input parameter. There is a Boolean property of x called permanent which is false. I'm wondering if this needs to be true, but I can't see how I can set that (I tried passing true as a second parameter, but VS complains then).

I have tried a number of options suggested on here but I can't get any of them to work. Most seem to produce syntax errors in the definition for me, which I know is probably down to the fact that I have done something wrong by not configuring it properly, but as I can't work out how it should be configured, my result is I can't get it to work.

Comment: As I said, I'm very new to this. I did tag it as razor-pages. To create the project in Visual Studio,  I selected Visual C#, Get Started, Web App.

Comment: The MVC in the definition of x is because that what the tooltip said Redirect returned. I originally had it as an int, but VS said couldn't implicitly convert to int so I defined it as VS said.

Comment: @TimFoster: Regarding your edit to the question... When you take a look at the linked duplicate and replicate what's happening in the accepted answer there, do you still have an error?  Can you show the code which produces that error and specify exactly what the error is?